# Delete not working in crud functionality (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having something is not working within my controller in that the specific items that I have in my app are not deleting when the button is being hit. I've tried adding a binding.pry right at the beginning of my destroy method, and its not getting hit. As a result i'm not sure what I am doing wrong that is keeping my items from being deleted without using the rails console.

Would anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

My `controller`

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def destroy
   @item.destroy
   redirect_to root_path
 end

end
```

My `show` page

```
%h1= @item.title
%h3= @item.description

= link_to "Home", root_path
= link_to "Edit", edit_item_path(@item)
= link_to "Delete", item_path(@item), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}
```

My routes page is like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :items
 root 'items#index'
end
```

My `application.js` file I have this

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered html for that page? from when you inspect element on the browser.

Comment: So in my inspect element, looking at the delete button, i'm getting 

<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/items/4">Delete</a>

When I press the button pretty much nothing is happening.

Comment: can you show your `application.js`  file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any delete queries in your `destroy` action.

Try:

```
def destroy
  if @item.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    # Unable to delete ...
  end
end
```

Now the item should be deleted from the database and the user redirected after that.

Answer (score 1):

What does your `routes` file look like?

Do you have a route for a `delete` method?

What actually happens when you click the link that you created? What is logged to the console?

Also, you're not actually deleting anything as part of your destroy action. You're only redirecting to the `root_path`.